# No puedo salir del bucle "while" | c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, while

Estoy intentando hacer un juego de preguntas. Para que las preguntas sean aleatorias y no se repitan he creado un mecanismo para que se cree una frase con el index de la pregunta para no volver a repetirla. Sin embargo, aunque todo me sale sin errores, al ejecutar el código, parece que **no sale del bucle "while"** porque no se ejecuta lo siguiente.

He cambiado cosas para ver cuál es el fallo, pero no lo encuentro. Soy principiante, seguramente es una tontería. Si pueden decirme como mejorarlo, también lo agradezco.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
 class Program
 {
     static string frase_actualizada(string numeros, string aleatorio_string)
     {
         string resultado_final = numeros + aleatorio_string;
         return resultado_final;
     }
     
     static string[] preguntas_facil = { @"¿Cuándo se descubrió América?", "¿Cuántas revoluciones industriales se han producido?", "¿Cúántos dedos tiene un humano?", "¿Cuántas patas tienen las arañas?", "¿En qué año se produjo el 11S?" };

     static void preguntas(int aleatorio_int)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(preguntas_facil[aleatorio_int]);
     }

     static void Main(string[] args)
     { 
         int aleatorio_int;
         string frase = "";
         string aleatorio_string;

         while(!(frase.Contains("0")&&frase.Contains("1") && frase.Contains("2") && frase.Contains("3") && frase.Contains("4") && frase.Contains("5"))) 
         {
             Random n_aleatorio_inicial = new Random();
             aleatorio_int = n_aleatorio_inicial.Next(0, preguntas_facil.Length);

             aleatorio_string = Convert.ToString(aleatorio_int);
           
             if (frase.Contains(aleatorio_string))
             {
                 continue;
             }
             
             else
             {
                 preguntas(aleatorio_int);
                 
                 Console.WriteLine("hola");
             }
             frase = frase_actualizada(frase, aleatorio_string);
         }

         Console.WriteLine("hola");
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Tu bucle busca que haya 6 preguntas (0,1,2,3,4,5) pero vos solo tenes 5 preguntas... o sea, el 5 nunca va a aparecer...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Ejecute tu codigo y lo que pasa es que se imprimen las preguntas de forma aleatoria y el hola,  pero después de ello, solo se ejecuta:

```
if (frase.Contains(aleatorio_string))
{
    continue;
}
```

**¿Por qué pasa esto?**
1- La condición para que el bucle se rompa dice: mientras !(frase contenga 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, y 5).
Esta condición siempre será true especificamente así !(false) => true, y me dirás bueno pero por qué? si mi random number va desde 0  a la candidad de elementos de mi array que es 5. Resulta que el metodo .Next incluye el número menor (minValue), pero no el mayor (maxValue) por lo cual nunca se añadira el 5 en tu frase.

2- Una vez dentro del ciclo infinito, tenemos otra pregunta por que solo se ejecuta el bloque del if y no del else? seguro ya sabes la respuesta pero... frase ya contiene cualquier numero posible por lo que tenemos if(true) por así decirlo.

Puedo darte la solución para solucionar el problema pero creo que ya sabes cual es, así que mejor te dejaré unos tips para mejorar tu codigo:

- Sigue las convenciones Usa CamelCase con empezando con mayuscula para los metodos y camelCase empezando con minúscula para las variables o campos.
- Usa cada tipo de dato para la mejor tarea, no conviertas sino es necesario es mejor usar varios tipos de datos para mejorar la semantica y estructura de tu codigo, aunque debas cambiar la lógica del mismo.
- Sin importar porque estes codeando, ya sea un proyecto personal/profesional,  practica o tarea; trata de darle sentido a tu codigo(lo digo sin mala intención) por ejemplo en este caso puedes usar un ReadLine de la clase Console y así darle la oportunidad al usuario de contestar las preguntas.

Espero que esto te haya ayudado y hayas podido resolver el problema, Bye

Answer (score -1):

Espero serte de ayuda en algo, yo no tengo mucha experiencia en c#, pero, la logica deberia ser la misma que c++.

en ocasiones si haces un while, necesitas algo que rompa el ciclo, por decirlo asi, una variable booleana que inicie en false y cambie su estado a true dentro del ciclo cuando ocurra algo.

o bien puedes usar un ciclo do - while() donde la condicion del while sea por ejemplo cuando opcion sea diferente de 5 sal de aqui. algo asi

```
do{
   cosas que hacer mientras se cumpla el ciclo
   }
while(op!=5);  // el ciclo funcionara hasta que opcion sea diferente de 5
```

Espero haberte ayudado en algo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!!! tene en cuenta ver [answer]... por como esta estructurada, esto parece mas un comentario que una respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, es primera vez que interactuo en la pagina.

Comment: No hay problema. Tene en cuenta que esta respuesta puede ser borrada, porque en realidad no es una respuesta. Las respuestas deben ser completas y solucionar el problema. Mira por favor el [tour] para saber como funcionamos... Bienvenido!